# Excel graph: macro for user defined variable line thickness

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have multiple data series in a graph and I want each of about 55 lines in the graph to have different thickness based on my choice. I have seen the following macro to adjust thickness of all lines in one go.

```
Sub SetWeights()
    Dim srs As Series
    For Each srs In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection
        srs.Format.Line.Weight = 0.75
    Next
End Sub
```

1. Is there any way (macro) so that each line will have different thickness as defined in one of the columns in the Excel worksheet?
2. Is there any similar way to change line colour as well as marker type in one go (no need of different marker for each line)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can format line thickness and colour.

This code should format series 2:

```
Sub SetWeights()
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
With Selection.Format.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(107, 197, 135)
    .Weight = 1
End With
End Sub
```

You could modify the code to loop through each series, and each time read a different colour and weight.

You can change marker type by adding a line like:

```
.MarkerStyle = -4142
```

Options for marker style are listed here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/series-markerstyle-property-excel

Comment: This is a nice information. However, as I don't know much (rather anything) about coding a macro, can you please advise on the full code for this? I don't even know how to 'loop'(?)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the following macro (obtained from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437999/auto-adjust-excel-chart-line-weights-with-a-loop) answers my original question.

```
Sub SetWeights()
    Dim Srs As Series
    Dim myWeight As Range
    Dim £w As Range
    Dim j As Long

    Set myWeight = Range("Weights")

    j = 1

    With ActiveSheet
        For Each £w In myWeight
            If j > ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count Then Exit Sub
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).Format.Line.Weight = £w
            j = j + 1
        Next £w
    End With
End Sub
```

...and I'm able to plot such graph:
[Able to draw this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tiwk1.jpg)

Can anyone provide any modification to this macro so that I will be able to have such graph?

[New expected graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZ6sZ.jpg)

Thank you!

Comment: Your pictures clarify what you're trying to do.  Unfortunately, line weight is applied to the entire series.  I think the only way you could do this is to divide each of your series into two separate series.  eg the "fat" portion would be one series, and the "thin" portion another.  Then format them with the same color, but different line weights.  The data point where the thickness changes would have to be in both series.